# Tor not working with IDM extension - 13 Sep 2018

Tags: error, update

Tor not working with IDM extension - 13 Sep 2018 - previously Tor was running smoothly with IDM installed, i updated both Tor and IDM to date, now tor runs in background (task manager) but not upfront, it runs without the IDM extension, i have win10 Pro and NPAV antivirus, can't figure out the problem is in TOR, IDM or Antivirus, how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the extension in TOR. The new update of TOR is based on  Firefox version 60.2 the old TOR used idmmzcc2.xpi of IDM (which will not work to this newer version, Try installing the idmmzcc3.xpi since it support the new version of Firefox and other browser. BTW the new update of IDM seems to be blocking (not allowing) downloads using VPN or any anonymity tools.